# Android Studio : Icon next to text in a button

Tags: java, android, android-button, material-components-android

I am developing an app using android studio and I want to add an icon to a text in the button, like this :

[image: button]

here is my xml code:

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
            android:text="@string/conducteur"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/main_blue"
            app:cornerRadius="20dp" />
```

Thank you for helping me;

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `app:icon` attribute to define the icon and the **`iconGravity`** attribute to define the position.

The default value `app:iconGravity="start"`

```
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            app:iconGravity="start"
            android:text="BUTTON"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_24px"/>
```

or `app:iconGravity="textStart"`

```
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            app:iconGravity="textStart"
            android:text="BUTTON"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_24px"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `app:icon` to specify a drawable for this button :

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/conducteur"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_home"/>
```

Comment: No problem, don't hesitate to look in the documentation of each component when you search something. Here for MaterialButton : https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton#attr_MaterialButton_icon